# leading zero in varchar field in settings table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my database I've got a table called settings. It has two columns, `name` and `value`.

I'm trying to insert a phone number, for example `0612345678` in it.

It keeps removing the leading zero (result `612345678`).

I use `$value = strval($value);` to be sure that PHP passes the value as a string (which I can confirm, works).

Is this a MySQL default setting or can I fix this?

Comment: Integers values cannot start with 0.

Comment: data type of `value`? show your `CREATE TABLE` command.

Comment: If its a varchar, it should be the string and not remove any leading zeros. You said you confirmed that from PHP its the proper value? Can you show how you insert it?

Comment: You should be storing those phone numbers as text, I think, in your MySQL table.  What is the target column and what is that column's type?

Comment: @B.Desai, it's a `varchar` field (as said in the title) :)

Comment: @Qirel, the value is entered `$value = strval($value);`

Comment: show your insert code then

Comment: You may need to set as varchar the column to avoid remove the 0. Logically if a number has a 0 in the first position this is useless. You won't need to calculate anything with this numbers due are phone numbers. So you can try to change the type of value

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes I know, but it is a settings table, it holds more values, that why I chose the `varchar` column type.

Comment: If it's already `varchar`, then the leading zero should not be getting stripped, which would seem to point fingers at the PHP side of things.

Comment: Make sure your value not being converted to int before you do `$value = strval($value);` in php

Comment: @B.Desai, it is inserted through a OOP database class. As said, I'm sure the value PHP sends to the server is a string (since I use `strval()`). If I echo after `$value = strval($value);`, it gives me `0612345678`...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep leading zero, you need to store the values in a string column (which I guess is an integer now either in PHP or in MySQL) .

The other option is to add the number while selecting (not recommended )

```
SELECT LPAD( Column, <lengthOfOriginalNumber>, '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either `php` or `MySQL` is converting phone number into a `number` and hence, leading zeros are stripped.

- If it's `php` then you can use `strval` function to get the String value (explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php)). Also, you can try printing the value before it gets sent to `MySQL` to see the result after conversion.
- If it's `MySQL` then you need to change the column type to be `varchar`, e.g.:

  `ALTER TABLE table MODIFY phone_number VARCHAR(20);`

Comment: Both conversions are already there. OP already mention that in question

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I use `strval`, see question. And I use a varchar column, see title.

Comment: @LinkinTED in that case, can you try printing `$value` in the console after conversion, to see what the new value is?